# How to send more than one object to WCF Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am having a wcf service to which i am sending one list as below method.
But i want to send two parameters like below approach means that could be a list or any object same as entity in service layer by post method.
Is this Possible?

Below is the process by which i am doing to send array of objects to Service.and it is working well.

**jquery code :**

> ```
>       var listOfObjects=new Array();
> ```

```
      //creating list of objects
      for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
       {   var MyEntity=new Object();
           MyEntity.TestId =i;
           MyEntity.TestId =i+"testName";
           listOfObjects.push(MyEntity);
       }

       var jsonList=JSON.stringify(listOfObjects);
       var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonData+'';

        //Saving info
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: dataToSend,
            url: "../ServiceLayer/myService.svc/SaveResults",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",          
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
```

**WCF :**

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public void SaveLabResults(List<MyEntity> myEntity)
    {
          var lstEntities=myEntity;
    }
```

**Entity:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TestId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just add in another parameter.

```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public void SaveLabResults(List<MyEntity> myEntity,List<MyEntity> myEntity2)
    {
          var lstEntities=myEntity;
          var lstEntities2=myEntity2;
    }
```

And:

```
var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonData+', "myEntity2":'+jsonData2+' }';
//Saving info
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: dataToSend,
    url: "../ServiceLayer/myService.svc/SaveResults",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",          
    success: function () {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to send more than one parameter, you just have to declare them on both, the web method and on the client side:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public void SaveLabResults(List<MyEntity> myEntity, SomeObject secondParameter)
{
      var lstEntities=myEntity;
}
```

And on the client side:

```
var dataToSend = '{"myEntity":'+jsonData+', "secondParameter":'+secondObject+'}';
```

The parameter names must match on both, the server and the client side.